# A Google-cloud-storage "folder" looks like an object (Spark generated parition)

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, google-cloud-storage

**TL;DR** - I have a "folder" (I'm aware that technically there are no folders) that looks like an actual object, with zero size.

#### How does it look like?

See the output of `gsutil`'s long listing (some names redacted and changed):

```
╰─$ gsutil ls -l "gs://.../hive-warehouse/some.db/test/partDate=2022-05-24/mainType=entity/**"
         0  2022-05-24T00:51:37Z  gs://.../hive-warehouse/some.db/test/partDate=2022-05-24/mainType=entity/
    450940  2022-05-24T00:51:38Z  gs://.../hive-warehouse/some.db/test/partDate=2022-05-24/mainType=entity/mainId=123/part-00041-....c000.csv.gz
    226889  2022-05-24T00:51:37Z  gs://.../hive-warehouse/some.db/test/partDate=2022-05-24/mainType=entity/mainId=456/part-00012-....c000.csv.gz
TOTAL: 3 objects, 677829 bytes (661.94 KiB)
```

The folder itself was **not** supposed to be listed as an object. This isn't the behavior when listing other folders.

Further using the "longer" listing of gsutil produces the following:

```
╰─$ gsutil ls -L gs://.../hive-warehouse/some.db/test/partDate=2022-05-24/mainType=entity/
gs://.../hive-warehouse/some.db/test/partDate=2022-05-24/mainType=entity/:
    Creation time:          Tue, 24 May 2022 00:51:37 GMT
    Update time:            Tue, 24 May 2022 00:51:37 GMT
    Storage class:          STANDARD
    Content-Length:         0
    Content-Type:           application/octet-stream
    Hash (crc32c):          AAAAAA==
    Hash (md5):             2B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg==
    ETag:                   CIzupN/aaBBcEAE=
    Generation:             1653351117573132
    Metageneration:         1
    ACL:                    []
                                 gs://.../hive-warehouse/some.db/test/partDate=2022-05-24/mainType=entity/mainId=123/
                                 gs://.../hive-warehouse/some.db/test/partDate=2022-05-24/mainType=entity/mainId=456/
TOTAL: 1 objects, 0 bytes (0 B)
```

#### What generated that folder

We are using Google's managed Spark cluster (Dataproc) with the managed hive metastore that comes with it.
The following code created the `test` table:

```
      // someDf is a DataFrame
      someDf.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
        .format("csv")
        .partitionBy("partDate", "mainType", "mainId")
        .option("compression", "gzip")
        .option("header", value = true)
        .saveAsTable("test")
```

#### Attempted conclusion

From all the above it seems like Spark has created an empty object with the same name as the `mainType` partition (and only for that partition).
I'm not sure if the above means anything, or what else to make of it.
Would love to hear some experts (either Spark or GCP).

Comment: I cannot answer in your case, but a few commercial software packages, including one I wrote, create zero-length objects to **emulate** folders. They do nothing and can be deleted because the namespace is flat. They are just a convenience. However, I stored metadata in the object (folder last modified date and Linux permissions) so these objects might serve a purpose for file synchronization software or similar apps.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks . Yes I understand. But Spark created this folder, and it's odd that it did, esp. since it was only for that specific partition and not for the other ones.

Comment: As mentioned above, it's an issue on the Spark side. ```gsutil``` is only listing what it found :)